# How to use actually use span to embed videos with twitter bootstrap?

Tags: css, iframe, twitter-bootstrap

I need to embed a youtube clip within a webpage and I use twitter bootstrap. How does one correctly actually use span correctly to embed the video?

There are so many resolutions out there! For example, if I choose span8 for the video - it would be ~620 pixels wide iframe video. This may be an issue with even smaller resolutions.

Comment: Duplicate with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166784/how-to-implement-a-responsive-youtube-embed-iframe-with-twitter-bootstrap

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the width and height of the iframe relative to (100%) the containing `div span*`. Choose a span width which fits your design.
If you enable the responsive features of twitter bootstrap, see: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive the width of your span and so the iframe change with the resolution.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12235638/1596547 shows how to make the size of the iframe responsive.

Example see: http://bootply.com/BassJobsen/61833

Comment: Awesome! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Is there a similar solution for non-iframe <video> elements? (ie, for use with getUserMedia)

Comment: @geoff does this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101254/passing-data-to-bootstrap-modal-without-javascript/19203506 helps you?

Comment: This is not working with bootstrap 3. Can anyone help with the same?

Comment: if you replace the `span*` with `col-sm-*` i do not find a reason why it should not work?