# Passing data to Bootstrap Modal without JavaScript

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, lightbox, twitter-bootstrap-3, custom-data-attribute

I have a grid with image links on my page. When clicking one of them a modal should pop up with the image but in big format.

Now I'm trying to achieve this without the use of javascript/jquery but just with data-attributes.

At the moment I have this code:

```
<!-- Generating the image link with PHP (laravel) -->    
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal"> {{ HTML::image("img/$photo->Link", "$photo->Title", array("class"=>"thumbnail col-md-3")) }} </a>

<!--The modal -->
    <section class="row">
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                      <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                          <h4 class="modal-title text-center">HEADER</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                          <p> BODY </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                          <p>My Footer</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>      
        </section>
```

Is is possible to achieve this just with data-attributes without using javascript?

I'm using [Twitter Bootstrap Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) and [Lightbox for Bootstrap 3 Plugin](http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/)

**EDIT:**

```
<div  class="imgLink col-md-3"> 
    <a data-toggle="lightbox">
            <img src="../img/5.jpg" class="thumbnail"> 
    </a>
</div>
```

Of course I've added the script of the lightbox plugin and when clicking this I'm getting no remote access how come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use the lightbox plugin OR a modal.

### lightbox plugin

The plugin provide the modal stucture so you don't have to add the modal html structure to your source

1. include the javascript file from https://github.com/ashleydw/lightbox to your document: `<script src="//rawgithub.com/ashleydw/lightbox/master/js/ekko-lightbox.js"></script>`
2. add a link to your image with `data-toggle="lightbox"`:

-

```
<a href="http://distilleryimage6.ak.instagram.com/ba70b8e8030011e3a31b22000a1fbb63_7.jpg" data-toggle="lightbox">
<img src="http://distilleryimage6.ak.instagram.com/ba70b8e8030011e3a31b22000a1fbb63_7.jpg" class="img-responsive">
</a>
```

Except from the plugin no further javascript needed.

**update**

> can I add a title to this lightbox(like a header in a modal?)

The plugin seems to have the option to set a title / footer. But the current version doesn't have the right structure to set them. I rewrite the plugin to better fit Bootstrap 3, see: https://github.com/bassjobsen/lightbox. Now you can set the title with `data-title` like:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <a id="mylink" data-title="My LightBox" href="http://distilleryimage6.ak.instagram.com/ba70b8e8030011e3a31b22000a1fbb63_7.jpg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="multiimages" class="col-sm-4">
                                <img src="http://distilleryimage6.ak.instagram.com/ba70b8e8030011e3a31b22000a1fbb63_7.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
</div>  
</div>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/85855

### Bootstrap's Modal:

The modal has an option to provide a remote URL. This should be a valid url which provide the modal structure, see:  [Bootstrap 3 with remote Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378720/bootstrap-3-with-remote-modal). So it is not possible to load the image direct in your modal via a data attribute. Other answers like https://stackoverflow.com/a/18463703/1596547 demonstrate how to do that. With these answers in combination with https://stackoverflow.com/a/10863680/1596547 you could write something like:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {

            $('<img class="img-responsive" src="'+ e.relatedTarget.dataset.remoteImage+ '">').load(function() {
  $(this).appendTo($('#myModal .modal-body'));
});
});
```

If you also add a modal structure with id `#myModal` to your source it will be possible to load your images in a modal with:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-remote-image="http://distilleryimage6.ak.instagram.com/ba70b8e8030011e3a31b22000a1fbb63_7.jpg" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">show image</a>
```

demo: http://bootply.com/85814

Comment: Trying to use the lightbox plugin but when doing what you said I'm getting: `No remote target given` in my lightbox I'll update my question with a snippet to the code

Comment: There is no remote target, you will have to add the url of the image to the href attribute. Like: `<a href="http://distilleryimage6.ak.instagram.com/ba70b8e8030011e3a31b22000a1fbb63_7.jpg" data-toggle="lightbox">
<img src="http://distilleryimage6.ak.instagram.com/ba70b8e8030011e3a31b22000a1fbb63_7.jpg" class="img-responsive">
</a>`

Comment: ooh okay cool! working, side question: can I add a title to this lightbox(like a header in a modal?)

Comment: i don't know, i will look at it. I also don't see a close button (default setting). Did you also try the Bootstrap's Modal solution? It's easy to add a title and close to the modal (it is there already). Or could you tell me what's the difference between a modal and a lightbox in general?

Comment: see the update of my answer about how to add a tittle

Comment: The difference between Modal and Lightbox plugin: You can have gallery and use it as a gallery going to next/previous photo. Also you picture automatically is shown on highest resolution

Comment: When using your rewriten plugin, when clicking on an image link the image just opens in a new window, a lightbox is not being shown

Comment: @mXX their must be an error some where. Could you add your code in a bootply or fiddle? This http://bootply.com/85855 works for you?