# How can I not truncate my div with video player and bootstrap 3.0

Tags: amazon-s3, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using this template :

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/

When i put my S3 video player, in big size, it's ok like here :
 [image: Screen]
<sub>(source: [free.fr](http://desfurets.free.fr/photo/upload/cpomzodrun4s9xhdsy7ubhvajvvzvo.jpg))</sub>

But if i reduce the size of my page, i've got this:
 [image: Screen]
<sub>(source: [free.fr](http://desfurets.free.fr/photo/upload/t6dh50tegor6xrbjnnvre5f905rnav.jpg))</sub>

My line code is :

```
<div class="jumbotron">
        <p><strong>Module 1 :</strong> <a name="un">Introduction</a></p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    <!-- Script for video S3 -->
    </script>
    <p>Description</p>
      </div>
```

How can i keep the width of the div that contain my video with Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

Could you also add an example of the javascript you use? You will have to try to set the width of your embedded code to 100%.

I tried some example code from: http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/2010/03/using-amazon-s3-to-host-streaming-videos/:

```
<script src="http://www.onthegosystems.com/mediaplayer/swfobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="mediaspace">This text will be replaced</div>

<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
var so = new SWFObject('http://www.onthegosystems.com/mediaplayer/player.swf','mpl','640','467','9');
so.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');
so.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
so.addParam('wmode','opaque');
so.addVariable('file','http://d1ftqtsbckf6jv.cloudfront.net/using_glossaries.mp4');
so.write('mediaspace');
// ]]></script>
```

Al thought the width is hardcoded here, you could also manipulate it with javascript:

```
 $('#mediaspace embed').attr('width','100%');
```

Also read this part of the docs: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#third-parties. The docs have a Google maps example now but this issue will be happen for all kind of third party content.

For TB2 i used this: [How to implement a responsive Youtube embed iframe with Twitter Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166784/how-to-implement-a-responsive-youtube-embed-iframe-with-twitter-bootstrap) should work for TB3 too.